# Calculating Heat Flux numerically using Fourier's Law for a 2D Domain

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, physics, heat-equation

I have computed in a 2d mesh the velocity and temperature, denoted by the matrices U and T respectively. Say, for a square domain, how would I go about computing the individual heat flux components at each of the boundary points? I am currently using the FDM scheme
$$ q = -k\nabla T $$
$$ q = -k \frac{T_{i+1,j}-T_{i,j}}{\Delta x} $$
but it seems to be yielding incorrect values.

Comment: Can you elaborate? What do you mean by "incorrect values"? What are you comparing them to?

Comment: I'm using this to calculate the heat transfer coeff and the Nusselt number - I'm getting values of 6.5 when they should be about half I believe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out - revise average temperature on the basis of velocity - $T_m$ must also factor in $U_m$